# How one integrate both sides of the inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I have an inequality of the form:

$$u′(x)>-g′(x)$$ for $$x∈[a,c)$$

Here the interval is open.

My question is: How one integrate both sides of the inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x_0, x \in [a,c)$:
$$
\int\limits_{x_0}^x\! u'(\xi) \, d\xi > 
- \int\limits_{x_0}^x\! g'(\xi) \, d\xi \iff \\
u(x) - u(x_0) > -(g(x)-g(x_0))
$$

Comment: But the inequality is not holds at $c$.

Comment: You should provide all information on the problem in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you unknow $u'$ and $g'$ it not possible know the behavior of $u$ and $f$. Hence It not possible in one integrate both sides of the inquality know the behavior of the final expression.